# Angularjs html tags showing instead of rendering

Tags: html, angularjs, rendering

I have the following variable:

```
$scope.someVar= "Some<br>text<br>here";
```

When I call it in the HTML document with `{{ someVar }}` I get the following output:

> `Some<br>text<br>here`

I would like the following output:

> Some
> text
> here

What can I do so the HTML code is rendered?

Thank you in advance for all suggestions.

Comment: use `ng-bind-html` from [`ngSanitize`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngSanitize) module. You can also `$compile` it from a directive

Comment: Hi @AlekseySolovey , thanks for your reply. I just started angularjs. Not sure how to use that, but if I am not mistaken I need to do that the following way: <span ng-bind-html="someVar"></span>. Can I apply it somehow with the {{someVar}} code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `ng-bind-html`

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['ngSanitize']);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.myText = "My name is: <h3>John Doe</h3>";
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular-sanitize.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

<p ng-bind-html="myText"></p>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you @VipulSolanki It worked. Is it any way possible to use `ng-bind-html` when calling the variable between the brackets (`{{someVar}}`)? or do I have to use an HTML tag?

Comment: like this `<p>(<ng-bind-html ng-bind-html="myText"></ng-bind-html>)</p>` ? or do you want to use this variable in function?

Comment: I have it like this: `<p>{{ varOne }} {{ varTwo }} <span ng-bind-html="varThree"></span></p>` at the moment, and would like to have `<p>{{ varOne}} {{ varTwo }}  {{ varThree }}</p>`. If that is possible. varOne and varTwo work fine as they have no HTML tags.

Comment: Yes, you can. if `varOne` or `varTwo` has possibly html value or not, you can use like `<p><span ng-bind-html="varOne"></span> <span ng-bind-html="varTwo"></span> <span ng-bind-html="varThree"></span></p>`. if variable has html code it converted otherwise it'll return actual value.

Answer (score 1):

Other solution :
you can use $sce, 
example : 
html:

```
<div ng-app="testApp" ng-controller="testController">
    <p ng-bind-html="someVar"></p>
</div>
```

js:

```
var app = angular.module('testApp', []);

app.controller('testController', ['$sce', '$scope', function($sce, $scope) {

    $scope.someVar =  $sce.trustAsHtml("Some<br>text<br>here");
}]);
```